# .NET Localization without directory structure

Tags: .net, wpf, localization

I'm working to build a .NET program with WPF that will need to be localized. I have looking into localizing the app with LocBaml and by using .resx files. However, both of these options require a specific directory structure to be in place. I would like to deploy the program using IExpress ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IExpress)) to allow the end user to download a self-extracting file. However, IExpress only packs up a list of files and does not maintain any kind of directory structure, which throws a wrench in the localization plans. Has anyone experienced an issue like this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get around the lack of directory structure when using IExpress, you can supply a command-line script (.cmd file) to set up your directory structure and copy files to the appropriate places.  You simply include this script in the package and set a 'Post Install Command' to run the script.

Script example:

```
@md french
@xcopy /q /y FR_docs.txt french\.
@xcopy /q /y FR_library.dll french\.
@xcopy /q /y FR_something.etc french\.
```

The process is discussed in the msdn documentation here: [Using IExpress Wizard to Create a DPInst Installation Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms790441.aspx)